# Simplest way to manage centralized git repositories on a Linux box?

Tags: linux, git, repository

I want to use my Linux home server as a central repo for having access to my git projects anywhere.

I've heard about gitosis, but was wondering if there might be a simpler/better way, maybe more native to linux and git itself (i.e. no python), to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For stuff I don't put on GitHub, I remote my git repos via SSH in a user directory.  See [this blog post](http://toolmantim.com/articles/setting_up_a_new_remote_git_repository) for an example.  That works pretty well and is very simple.